# Website's .PNG logo is off-centre in mobile/responsive view, but OK only on desktop browser view

Tags: html, css, png, graphical-logo

[Here's the website in question](http://staging.twotailsmedia.com).  If you view the site on a desktop browser (I've tried Chrome, Firefox, Edge) it looks fine.  But when you view it on any mobile device the top logo is off-centred and in the wrong spot- [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysjRA.jpg).

Here's the relevant line of code from my index.html file:

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <span class="imagetop"><img src="images/TTM-Logo3.png" alt="" /></span>
    </div>
```

And here's the code from my .css file:

```
.imagetop {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

A few days ago I thought that I had this fixed, but unfortunately it came back to haunt me.  I even tried rolling back to a previous version of the site, but am still encountering the same issue.

Any thoughts on what I can do to properly centre the logo at the top, both in desktop and mobile viewing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the responsive `width` and `height` are overwriting the default styles (on `736px` and smaller). Resetting the code should bring it back to normal. All you will have to set is the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
    #header .logo {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        line-height: initial;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this one- it works, too!  And even better I don't have to manually change the 'height'. :)